# What means $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in the equation $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ = $\operatorname{Ran}(A)+ \operatorname{Ker}(A^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

What means $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ in the equation $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\operatorname{Ran}(A)+ \operatorname{Ker}(A^T)$? Is it the number of the columns of $A$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$? And what is the difference between row-rank and column-rank?

Comment: What do you mean with $\operatorname{Ran}$?

Comment: Ran should be the Range of A, and Ker(A) is the eigenspace of A

Comment: @Bernard: Range or Image, I'd suspect.

Comment: It's quite confusional with the rank. I'd say ‘Image’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better question is: what does the right hand side mean?

$\operatorname{Ran}(A)$ is the column space—the span of the columns of $A$.

$\operatorname{Ker}(A^T)$ is the null space of $A^T$.

$+$ means to add together all pairs of vectors one from each space: $V + W = \{v + w : v \in V, w \in W\}$.

For example, let $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. Then

$$\operatorname{Ran}(A) = \operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} = \operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

(Use row reduction to find a basis.)

$$\operatorname{Ker}(A^T) = \operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$

(Because I picked $A$ such that $(1,1,2) + (0,1,-1) = (1,2,1)$—you can also use row reduction to find this.)

And finally

\begin{align} \operatorname{Ran}(A) + \operatorname{Ker}(A^T) &= \operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right\} + \operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \\ &= \operatorname{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} = \mathbf{R}^3. \end{align}

Comment: If you try a non-square matrix, you'll see what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: @CameronBuie I don't know what you mean. If you were to delete the third column from $A$, the range of $A$ and the kernel of $A^T$ remain the same.

Comment: Correct, but then $A$ is $3\times 2,$ and not $3\times 3.$

Comment: @CameronBuie So it should be $\mathbf{R}^m$ instead of $\mathbf{R}^n$ when $A$ is $m \times n$. But that's a problem with what is written in the question, not in my answer.

Comment: I'm also used to the convention that vectors are column vectors unless otherwise specified, so that the image of a linear transformation is the column space of its associated matrix. However, this convention is not universal, so care should be taken to determine which convention is being used, if relevant. Here, it is both relevant and implied by the context given, but not explicitly stated. You'll see that I addressed the post's ambiguity in my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb R^n$ is the $n$-dimensional real vector space. The row space and columns space are the spans of the row vectors and column vectors of a matrix (respectively), but row rank and column rank (the dimensions of these spaces) are equal.

So, what this equation means is that every $n$-dimensional real row vector can be obtained as a linear combination of elements of the row space of $A$ and elements of the null space of $A^T.$ Had we been considering column vectors instead of row vectors, then we would have $\Bbb R^m,$ instead.

Comment: Is then the columspace just another name for column rank?

Comment: No. The column rank is the dimension of the column space. One is a number, the other is a vector space.